# How do you call JavaScript delete from Kotlin?

Tags: javascript, kotlin

I am working with a third party library from Kotlin and one of the things I must do is call `delete thing[key]` in order to remove an item from thing.  I am unable to figure out how to do this from Kotlin code.

I did try `js("delete thing[key]")`, but thing is a parameter to a function and is name-mangled by the Kotlin > JavaScript compiler so an exception is thrown when the line is executed.  I also tried `js("delete ") thing[key]` but unsurprisingly that didn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `delete` operator You can write:

```
external fun delete(p: dynamic): Boolean = noImpl
//...
delete(thing[key])
```

For more convenient use I'd added some helpers:

```
fun delete(thing: dynamic, key: String) {
  delete(thing[key])
}

// or
fun String.deleteFrom(d: dynamic) {
  delete(d[this])
}

fun test(a: Any, k: String) {
    delete(a, k)
    k.deleteFrom(a)
    k deleteFrom a
}
```

Note: using the delete operator is not a good practice and it'll leads to deoptimizations in JS VMs